# Cloth behaves strangely when trying to make a coat

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to make a coat and use the cloth modifier. I enabled colision but the mech of the coat just colapses.
[image]

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: In physics simulaton anytime helps a lot if you increase the scales drastically.

Comment: It only helped a litle bit. Is there another way?

Comment: There are many settings. You can increase the Quality Steps or the Collision's Quality. Or try to make more even faces (almost square instead of rectangles).